# See the present folder when recursive search for files inside root folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this to choose a root folder and take the newest file from each directory before adding this files into my `listbox` and i wonder if there is a way to know the present directory in order to update my UI while i am still search for files.

```
var rootDirFile = Directory
                        .EnumerateFiles(pathToSearch, "*.pcap", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                        .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f))
                        .Take(1);

                    var allNewestFilesOfEachFolder = Directory
                        .EnumerateDirectories(pathToSearch, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Select(d => Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.pcap")
                            .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f))
                            .FirstOrDefault());

foreach (string tempFile in rootDirFile.Concat(allNewestFilesOfEachFolder))
{
   //add the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to call your code via a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) with the `WorkerSupportsProgress` property set to `true`, and then handle the `ReportProgress` event

Comment: can i have an example ? (i am a new developer...)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code helps to resolve your problem

```
// Observable collection is the best choice to bind to the UI elements it automatically refreshes the changes in the UT whenever the data modifies. 

    ObservableCollection<string> objList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

          //Bind this ObservableCollection to the UI Element with TwoWay binding

          var rootDirFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathToSearch, "*.pcap", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f)).Take(1);
           // add to the observable collection

          var allNewestFilesOfEachFolder = Directory
                        .EnumerateDirectories(pathToSearch, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

           // Instead of Iterating the Directory in a single time, seperate the task and iterate folder by folder basis.

            foreach (string obj  in allNewestFilesOfEachFolder )
            {
                var dir = Directory
                        .EnumerateFiles(obj, "*.pcap", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                        .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f))
                        .Take(1);    

                // add to the observable collection , it will automatically reflects the changes in the UI            

            }
```

Let me know if you require binding code also. I'll explain briefly

Comment: i didn't understand what this code do, can you explain (i am a new developer)

Comment: Where you want to show the collection result, means of UI component?  Please learn binding and ObservableCollection in msdn. Then, you have a better understanding about this post.

Comment: i want to see the collection result on my label